# What is the use of typedef inside the class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have some code like this

```
class A : public b<T>
{
public:
    typedef b<T> _baseclass; // why we need this declaration 
};
```

What is the use of typedef inside the class?
Is the definition limited to this class only?
Shall we create this as static and use without crating an object of the class?

Comment: Look what what `typedef` is

Comment: Do you know what [`typedef`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typedef) does?

Comment: Yes it will help to give another name for the type. Ex typedef int INT; means int and INT same

Comment: So you just answered your own question

Comment: It just gives you a type alias.

Comment: @Nagappa So, if you already know what `typedef` does, what is the purpose of the question?

Comment: I know but any particular reason to define like this in c++?

Comment: @Nagappa It allows you to use `A::_baseclass` to find out what `A`'s base class is. It's presumably useful information in the context you found this piece of code in. Since you seem to be familiar with `typedef`, it's now clear what part of the posted code is confusing you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This member type will be available *outside* of the class definition too, which is convenient in template code. If you passed an `A` into a function template, or maybe some other classes that also have `_baseclass` member types, then you can use `_baseclass` to find out what the base is without needing to know exactly what the top-level type is.

Standard templates like `std::vector` and `std::map` have member types like `value_type` — these do not signify a base class but have a similar purpose, in that you can use `value_type` anywhere a container is used, no matter *which* container is used.

Swapping `typedef` to `using` (because I want to), here's an example:

```
// The class templates

template <typename T>
struct Base {};

struct A : Base<int>
{
    using base_class = Base<int>;
};

struct B : Base<char>
{
    using base_class = Base<char>;
};

struct C : Base<bool>
{
    using base_class = Base<bool>;
};


// The example

template <typename T>
void foo()
{
    // typename needed because base_class is a "dependent name"
    // (just go with it)
    typename T::base_class the_base;

    // This line is to suppress "unused variable" warnings
    (void)the_base;
}

int main()
{
   foo<A>();
   foo<B>();
   foo<C>();
}
```

Though this particular program doesn't actually "do anything", it shows a function template `foo` that can "know" what the base class was in each case, without any further information about exactly what `T` is. And it'll work for any class to which you've added a `base_class` member type!